# Check logged-in user in Apache in order to choose the right header

Tags: apache

I want to retrieve the connected user to transfer the rightAuthorization header. But the variable REMOTE_USER is empty.

Can you please help me.

I add the content of my VirtualHost.

---

Listen 8080

<VirtualHost *:8080>

<If "'%{REMOTE_USER}' == 'kirk'">
RequestHeader set Authorization "Basic dGVzdDp0ZXN0"


RequestHeader set Authorization "Basic dGVzdDp0ZXN0"

Require all granted
        Require valid-user

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Content"
AuthUserFile /etc/apache/Apache24/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests On
ProxyPass / http://kibana1:5601/
ProxyPassReverse /  http://kibana1:5601/

----------------

Regards

The variable REMOTE_USER is empty.